# Site is loading slowly. Is javascript the culprit?

Tags: javascript, performance, response

I suspect my site is loading slowly because of the numerous javascript references.  Would it be more efficient and proper if I combined all of the javascript files into one one file?

```
   <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.cycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.simplyscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.watermark.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
           ...
        });
    </script>
    <script src="files/js/runfunction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
           ...
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There's no way we can give you a useful answer based on the information provided. **You should measure for yourself** and see where the bottleneck is. [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and/or [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) are useful tools for this.

Comment: Use Firefox Firebug, Yslow, or Chrome developer tools to figure out why your site is slow. Sure, we all could make some guess, but what would that solve?? Hell, maybe the math co-processor had an overflow error that leaked out and shorted the RAM which is causing your browser to cry.

Comment: Use developer tools > net inspector and look at the timeline. It should give you a good idea of what causes the slowdown. Too many JavaScripts inside head section _can_ cause a delay; merging them could help.

Comment: Yes, measure for yourself.  There are plenty of tools to see what's loading slowly.  Even firebug for firefox will give you a good sampling of what's slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many other reasons that slow down your site. But at least you can use minified versions. Also combining them into one file as you said should help. Have a look at [Scott Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use webpagetest.org to generate a waterfall for the page load so you can see what's taking the time.